# CheckboxList not setting Selected with Viewstate disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, checkboxlist

I have a CheckboxList that seems to load and do everything right, except for when I do a postback, it will not have the `Item.Selected` property set. I have viewstate disabled for the entire page.

I load it like so(inside `Page_Load` on every load):

```
foreach (DataRow service in d.Tables[0].Rows)
{
  cblServices.Items.Add(new ListItem((string)service["description"], service["id"].ToString()));
}
```

My markup is simple:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="cblServices" Width="300px"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

and then, I use basically something like this(in a _Click serverside event for a button)

```
foreach(ListItem item in cblServices.Items){
  if(item.Selected){
    MyLabel.Text+="selected: "+item.Value+item.Text;
  }
}
```

and MyLabel never has any text added to it. I can verify with the debugger that it does reach the _Click's foreach loop, but no item is ever selected. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Did I read your post correctly in that you have viewstate *disabled*?

Comment: @ahs yes, for the entire page. There are other things on the page that do not play nice with viewstate and plus there are performance things to consider

Comment: @ahs ahh, now I see my typo :P corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're filling it on every Page_Load call, not only when `Page.IsPostback = false` then you're reseting the client selection on postback.

**EDIT**
You should add your items on the PreInit or Init event, then you'll be able to keep the selected items correctly.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataRow service in d.Tables[0].Rows)
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Cla yea, but if I do not add the items again(when Page.IsPostback==true), then when it gets to _Click's foreach, it doesn't have any ListItems

Comment: @Cla (your edit) I do not have access to the Page_PreInit(working in a UserControl). Plus, that doesn't even make sense because the controls don't exist yet at PreInit

Comment: @Earlz: The only way to keep the state of dynamically added controls is adding them on init / preInit event. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/…. Could you try with the OnInit event instead. Didn't know it was a User Control

Comment: Yea, I'm trying to get my code to move. It's not the most trivial thing to just move though because it's dynamic..

Comment: Ok, now it works. Accepting this even though I hate this answer because it means that some dynamic things have to somehow be moved into Page_Init. I hate the page lifecycle..