# CheckBoxList gets cleared on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, checkboxlist

I am creating a custom view in a SharePoint visual Web Part using ASP.NET (Visual C#) and have a CheckBoxList, and a button.

MarkUp for the List & Button:

```
<td>
    <asp:checkboxlist ID="cblYearLst" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />
</td>
<td>
     <asp:Button ID="btnRefineSearch" Text="Refine Search" runat="server" />
</td>
```

I add items to the CheckBoxList on PreRender:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    if (LstYears != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < LstYears.Count(); i++)
        {
            cblYearLst.Items.Add(new ListItem(LstYears[i], LstYears[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

And I call the event Handler for the button on Page_Load:

```
btnRefineSearch.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnRefineSearch_Click);
```

All of the CheckBox list-items do not stay selected after the button is clicked. I can retrieve the selected values, but they won't display as selected. When I add the Click event handler for the button in the pre-render event, the data is displayed appropriately but the selected values can no longer be retrieved by my Click event.

Any ideas on what might be causing this behaviour??

Comment: I think you're adding the items too late in the cycle. Add them on PreInit on Init: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724771/checkboxlist-not-setting-selected-with-viewstate-disabled

Comment: @jfmags I have tried what you have suggested but the list no longer gets displayed.

Comment: @jfmags I set LstYears in Page_Load, should I do that OnInIt as well?

Comment: Yeah - you have to set it before you loop through it - or it won't have any items.

Comment: @jfmags I moved setting LstYears to OnInIt and the initial problem still resides

Comment: It sounds like something else is going on. Can you post the code where you retrieve the CheckboxList values?

Comment: I have it as a list, but it should be an array, i fixed that in my code and tried it but the problem is still there

Comment: @jfmags I stepped through and checked how many times Page_Load gets fired, and it gets fired twice on PostBack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, since I have AutoEventWireUp set to true as Keenan has suggested it should all work if I do it in the page_load.

The problem was that Page_Load was being called twice, and I discovered that this was because I was redirecting the user to the same URL with QueryString parameters. After I made the much needed changes, my code works very well.

`+1` `Keenan` for your help and thank you (`@jfmags`) for tipping me off by telling me you think it is something else.

:D

Answer (score 1):

Did you try moving the binding of the checkboxlist into the page_load instead of pre_render? Just an idea because it seems like the page is losing selections on postback and you are regenerating the options each time.

UPDATE: I created a quick page and this works correctly. Do you have your viewstate turned off for the entire page in your page directive, or possibly in the web.config? I see you have it enabled on the checkboxlist but maybe there is a global setting throwing you off.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnRefineSearch.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnRefineSearch_Click);
```

`List<string> LstYears = new List<string>();
    LstYears.Add("one");
    LstYears.Add("two");
    LstYears.Add("three");
    LstYears.Add("four");

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (LstYears != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < LstYears.Count; i++)
            {
                cblYearLst.Items.Add(new ListItem(LstYears[i], LstYears[i]));
            }
        }
    }
}

private void btnRefineSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Response.Write(cblYearLst.SelectedValue);
}`

Comment: Yes, that is what I did initially, but the CheckBoxList got cleared and a fellow programmer suggested to add CheckBoxList items on PreRender

Comment: The Pre_Render is too late in the lifecycle to add the options. Checkout [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) to see what happens and when.

Comment: I have set it to true in the page directive in the .aspx file too but ill check the web.config

Comment: I added a new page and tested your code and it seems to work. I have the same web.config file for both

Comment: I stepped through and checked how many times Page_Load gets fired, and it gets fired twice on PostBack